# How to make substrate-node-template accessible via wss connection?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, substrate-front-end

I just ran `substrate-node-template` on dedicated server and connected with `substrate-frontend-template`. Everything works fine with http(ws), but when I try to connect via https(wss) it's not working(?) because `--wss-port` in substrate-node isn't supported. How can I fix it?

Comment: You have to set up a secure websocket https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss

Comment: can you provide an error what you got while connecting to wss port.

Comment: Substrate doesnt support secure websocket --wss-port.